# Paypal PHP Rest API for credit card payment , how to handle the errors to show it to the users

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using Paypal PHP Rest API from [here](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php) for credit card payment. I can pay successfully with demo data. In real time  when a user faces error in credit card payment, I need a  way to show it in a user-friendly way rather than in a programmatic way.

From the [paypal developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) ,  I found the format of the error object returned but cannot figure out how to use that.

My code follows:

```
try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);


} catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {

echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($ex->getData());

}
```

With intentional input of wrong data, following error message was there:

```
        Exception: Got Http response code 400 when accessing 
    https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.

        string '{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":

    [{"field":"payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card",
    "issue":"Invalid expiration (cannot be in the past)"},

    {"field":"payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card.number",
    "issue":"Value is invalid"},{"field":
    "payer.funding_instruments[0].credit_card.cvv2",
    "issue":"Length is invalid (must be 3 or 4, 
    depending on card type)"}],"message":"Invalid request 
    - see details","information_link":
    "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps
/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":
"bdcc'... (length=523)
```

So how can I get the error object as said in the mentioned Paypal developer site and how to use that to show errors to a non-techie person?

Answer (score 3):

The error returned is in JSON format. You can use `json_decode` to decode it in PHP:

```
$error_object = json_decode($ex->getData());
switch ($error_object->name)
{
    case 'VALIDATION_ERROR':
        echo "Payment failed due to invalid Credit Card details:\n";
        foreach ($error_object->details as $e)
        {
            echo "\t" . $e->field . "\n\t" . $e->issue . "\n\n";
        }
        break;
}
```

Add whichever cases you would like to your switch. And you can add your own flair, parse the `$e->field` and `$e->issue` to display whatever you like, etc.

Comment: can you give  the url where paypal mentions this ?

Comment: From the link you posted [PayPal Developer Site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/) Request and response payloads are formatted as JSON. This is true for the SDK as well. As for the code, it's up to you to handle the errors how you see fit.